# Postgresql create tablespace permission denied on windows 10

Tags: sql, windows, postgresql, permissions

I'm trying to create a new tablespace in postgres on windows 10 on a new partition as original one is running out of space using command:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE tablespace_p
OWNER postgres
LOCATION 'P:\postgres_tablespace_p';
```

The issue is that I get permission denied error [42501]:

```
ERROR: could not set permissions on directory "P:\postgres_tablespace_p": Permission denied
SQL state: 42501
```

What can cause the issue? How to setup permissions/roles?

Comment: You can probably find better answers to this question at dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Ok, I found a solution by myself, had to add a new role for mentioned directory called 'Everyone' and add read/write permissions. I am not sure whether it's a good practice or not however works fine.

Comment: The postgresql service is running under windows with the built-in account NetworkService. Give only this account filesystem permissions instead of Everyone. Ideally, noone else should have permissions to the postgresql data directories.

Comment: @drafa thank you. I was adding logged in user and user groups but it did not work. Adding everyone worked.